# Updating data in SORM seems possible (even though I was told it aimed at immutable data...)

Tags: scala, orm, sorm

I was told that SORM aims at immutable data. It's not written on the website - at least not in the main parts I was looking at, so I was a bit surprized of the rigidity of the claim. I was just aware it would recommend to do so. But maybe I was just missing something.

The examples tell you to use a ".copy(propery = newvalue)" before calling a Db.save() on the object. So thats a hint.

I was interrested in what would happen if I would just change the data and update it in the database. Strangely the following just worked fine:

```
case class Agent( var name : String )

object Db extends Instance(
  entities = Set( Entity[Agent]() ),
  url = "jdbc:h2:mem:hansi"
)

class SORMTest  extends FunSuite {
  test("Update") {
    // Store values in the db:
    val agent = Db.save( Agent("test") )

    agent.name = "hansi"
    Db.save(agent)
}
```

It produced an update statement in the database that changed the name property for the corresponding id.

Is it kind of crazy to do so? Any comments from the developers?

Answer (score 3):

> I was told that SORM aims at immutable data. It's not written on the website

It's stated plenty of times that SORM strongly follows functional programming idioms. This implies operation on immutable data-structures only.

> The examples tell you to use a ".copy(propery = newvalue)" before calling a Db.save() on the object.

That's where you're wrong. The examples tell you to use `.copy(..)` to get an updated immutable value of the object it's called on, calling it before calling a `Db.save()` per se as in the following:

```
agent.copy(name = "new name")
Db.save(agent)
```

will have absolutely no effect, because, once again, `.copy()` **doesn't mutate** the object it's called on, instead it returns an updated copy of this object. So the proper use is the following:

```
val updatedAgent = agent.copy(name = "new name")
Db.save(updatedAgent)
```

or simply:

```
Db.save( agent.copy(name = "new name") )
```

But the fact is all the above has to do with SORM only as much as it has to do with functional programming in Scala in general. This is really a very basic stuff about how case classes are supposed to be used. So please do yourself a favor and introduce yourself to basics of functional programming. This will wipe out all the questions on SORM you've already had and, I'm sure, plenty of those which are comming up otherwise.

Your example works and it's supposed to, but it doesn't change the fact that it goes against the basic idioms of functional programming and as such is an unidiomatic use of SORM.

Comment: I don't like the aggressive or annoyed undertone of your response. You cut out the part where I said that I might just have been missing something. 

And now you got me wrong when I described the copy save procedure as I was well aware that copy does not change the state of the old object. It's kind of foolish to me to assume I wouldn't know.

And it might seem kind of foolish to you to not see the signs that SORM aims at purely functional style. But I didn't see them and I still wonder where I should have seen them.

Comment: There might be people like me who tend to see immutable data as a concept of functional programming that is not always the optimal approach. The Haskell Wiki e.g. claims: "Purely functional programs typically operate on immutable data." (whichever dog wrote this - I think its a quite appropiate quote). In Scala which is far from beeing a purely functional language I would not expect a "functional style"(as it is said on the SORM website) to be on the totaly pure side.

Comment: As this is something that seems to be different in SORM when compared to other Scala ORMs I would like to see it underlined in the documentation more clearly. But is's all up to you. I am not trying to make your work look less shiny or less valueable. I think you should be more explecit about the good things you are offering.

Comment: Still I was surprised that even though it is so SORM seems to handle this kind of "misuse". I was just curious what would happen. I wouldn't use it that way even in case I would like to. It might break anytime - you wouldn't have a test for some kind of misuse.

Comment: You have to admit that your questions are very vague, so what I'm doing is just trying to guess what you're really asking, so, surely, I may come up with some false assumptions, but I really don't see what part of my answer you find offensive. Functional way is almost always the best way. With you saying that you tend to see immutable data-structures as a not optimal approach I have to reinstate that you need to learn more about functional programming. Yes, the language is not pure, but its advanced users tend to use it in a pure way exclusively. Scalaz is there to support that statement.

Comment: Its not really fun disuccsing withsomebody who is always off what I was saying somehow. I said: "There might be people like me who tend to see immutable data as a concept of functional programming that is not always the optimal approach." You cite me saying: "you tend to see immutable data-structures as a not optimal approach". This is not the same. There is certainly cases where immutable data is not something you should use. You are trying to make a status claim out of it. The smart people are only using immutable data. Thats what you say in the end. And thats gross nonsense in two ways.

Comment: Firtsly I don't see why one should need that kind of status game and secondly neither immutable data nor mutable data are bad concepts. It just depends on what you want to achieve. It seems to me you are sayng that smart people are always using hammers no matter what the screws look like anyway.

Comment: asides all the nonsense: I would really recommen you to call SORM not "functional style" but "purely functional" - this would be the right term to use for you kind of concept.

Comment: The questions you've asked and the fact that you've been suggesting to call a primarily effectful library purely functional led me to some conclusions about your expertise in functional programming, according to which I've made several attempts to help you resolve your problem. All I got in return were accusations and even an attempt to ridicule me with a hammer and screw metaphor by taking my words out of context. I see no point in continuing this conversation, that's besides the fact that starting from how the initial question was asked this thread violates multiple StackOverflow policies.